# How to change other values along with size change?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute, size-weight-units

When I change the size of configurable product, its price is changing. But along with that, I need to change the attribute value and other information as in the following image also. How can we do that?

**It changes the total price only**

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if I get you correctly,bu when you make a configurable product and add simple products to it, you can pick which attributes you want to change along. Check this tutorial https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-create-configurable-product-magento-2.html

Comment: Yeah, in that I selected size as the changing product in configurable product. But need to change the width, break up price and other attributes in the product page when that size is changed from 11 to 12.